# Select Distinct Rows And Include Non-Distinct Identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider a table like the following.

```
ID  Value   Change_Date
1   A       1/1/2017
1   B       1/2/2017
1   B       1/3/2017
2   C       1/1/2017
2   C       1/3/2017
3   D       1/1/2017
3   E       1/3/2017
3   F       1/4/2017
3   D       1/10/2017
```

I would like to perform a select statement which effectively does a distinct, but includes the change_date value of the first chronological occurrence of the distinct row. So the above table would be rendered into something like this:

```
ID  Value   Change_Date
1   A       1/1/2017
1   B       1/2/2017
2   C       1/1/2017
3   D       1/1/2017
3   E       1/3/2017
3   F       1/4/2017
3   D       1/10/2017
```

Is this even remotely possible in Oracle? I'm trying to weed out a bunch of dummy updates from an audit table, but need the change_date so I can show when it changed from value to value. A query like

```
select distinct id, value from my_table
```

will obviously get me seed information, but I need to tie it back to the proper dates. I could possibly use this and min(change_date), but that would mean the query would see the first row for id 3 as being the same as the last row for id 3, which is not correct.

EDIT: Please note, I'm not looking for the simple distinct on ID and Value. I need to also include when it switches back to a previous value, as seen for ID 3. All four values of ID 3 should be preserved in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to only want the first row when multiple id/value pairs are in a row.  Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (partition by id order by change_date) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
where prev_value is null or prev_value <> value;
```