# Get distinct rows for non-key values including keys without window functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following tables and data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Foo
(
    FooID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FooValue char(1) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Bar
(
    FooID int NOT NULL,
    BarID int NOT NULL,
    BarValue char(1),
    CONSTRAINT BarPK PRIMARY KEY (FooID, BarID),
    CONSTRAINT FooBar FOREIGN KEY (FooID) REFERENCES Foo(FooID)
);

INSERT INTO Foo(FooID, FooValue) VALUES
    (100, 'A'),
    (101, 'A'),
    (102, 'B'),
    (103, 'C'),
    (104, 'C');

INSERT INTO Bar(FooID, BarID, BarValue) VALUES
    (100, 1, 'X'),
    (100, 2, 'Y'),
    (101, 1, 'X'),
    (101, 2, 'Y'),
    (101, 3, 'Z'),
    (102, 1, 'X'),
    (103, 1, 'Z'),
    (104, 1, 'Z');
```

From this data I want a single row for each distinct combination of `FooValue` and `BarValue` together with their keys. I don't really care which keys are returned, so a possible result set could look like this:

| FooID | BarID | FooValue | BarValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | A | X |
| 100 | 2 | A | Y |
| 101 | 3 | A | Z |
| 102 | 1 | B | X |
| 104 | 1 | C | Z |

Usually I would do something like this:

```sql
WITH NumberedRows AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                    (PARTITION BY F.FooValue, B.BarValue ORDER BY F.FooID DESC) AS nr,
                F.FooID, B.BarID, F.FooValue, B.BarValue
            FROM Foo F
                INNER JOIN Bar B
                    ON B.FooID = F.FooID
    )
SELECT FooID, BarID, FooValue, BarValue
    FROM NumberedRows
    WHERE nr = 1;
```

Unfortunately I can't use the above solution since I'm constained to not use a CTE or `ROW_NUMBER()` (or any other window function, so [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46345446) doesn't help). Is there another way I can get the desired result?

Comment: *"I'm constained to not use a CTE or ROW_NUMBER()"* why this very arbitrary requirement?

Comment: We're using an inhouse engine for SQL commands which "translates" the raw SQL for use with the targe DBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, ...). This works fine but has the downside that some language constructs are not supported.

Comment: Perhaps you should tag that technology too, so people fluent in its features (or lack of?) are able to give answers they know work.

Comment: This engine is written inhouse and not available outside our company.

Comment: Wouldn't updating the engine to support window functions make far more sense then..? They are a fundamental part of SQL. Otherwise, without knowing what other limitations and lack of functionality the engine has, I'm not really sure I want to provide an answer to be told "that won't work due to further arbitrary requirements."

Comment: A simple CTE is just syntactic sugar for a derived table - is that possible? Are you constrained to a single SQL statement?

Comment: @Larnu _Wouldn't updating the engine to support window functions make far more sense then_ it probably would, but this is not something I can influence.

Comment: @SMor a derived table would be possible, yes.

Comment: Just do `...FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()... ) NumberedRows WHERE rn = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use window functions, then you first need to find the maximum `Foo.FooID` value (as required from the window function clause `ORDER BY F.FooID DESC ... WHERE rn = 1`)

```
SELECT MAX(F.FooID) AS FooID, 
       B.BarID, 
       F.FooValue
FROM       Foo F
INNER JOIN Bar B
        ON B.FooID = F.FooID
GROUP BY B.BarID,
         F.FooValue
```

Once you get these values, you can join back with your two tables:

```
SELECT F.FooID, 
       B.BarID, 
       F.FooValue, 
       B.BarValue
FROM       Foo F
INNER JOIN Bar B
        ON B.FooID = F.FooID
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(F.FooID) AS FooID, 
                   B.BarID, 
                   F.FooValue
            FROM       Foo F
            INNER JOIN Bar B
                    ON B.FooID = F.FooID
            GROUP BY B.BarID,
                     F.FooValue           ) cte
        ON F.FooID    = cte.FooID
       AND B.BarID    = cte.BarID
       AND F.FooValue = cte.FooValue
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e38fa7c89a58757cae9cdbe724593d17).